# AT commands exchange with /dev/tty*

Tags: linux, go, at-command, modem

I have a device with a GPRS onboard. GPRS connects with the third-party application and it works. I need to know the signal strength of the connection, so, I use ATZ, then AT+CSQ commands. When I work using some terminal software it works. Then, I had tried to use https://github.com/ishuah/bifrost soft as a terminal. It works as well. But how can I simply communicate with a device, not using terminal, without re-connection or connection abortion, etc?

I tried simply `echo ATZ > /dev/ttyX`  - no answer

```
    // This writes, but reads only zeros (((

    package main

    import (
        "github.com/jacobsa/go-serial/serial"
        "io"
        "log"
        "time"
        "fmt"
    )

    func Sleep(duration int) {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(duration))
    }

    func printBuf(b []byte){
        for _, val:=range b {
            fmt.Printf("%x ", val)
        }
    }


    func main(){

    options := serial.OpenOptions{
            PortName:              "/dev/ttyX",
            BaudRate:              115200,
            DataBits:              8,
            StopBits:              1,
            MinimumReadSize:       0,
            InterCharacterTimeout: 50,
        }

    port, err := serial.Open(options)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("port.Read: %v", err)
            return
        }

        // Make sure to close it later.
        defer port.Close()

    var s string  = `AT+CSQ`
    b:=[]byte(s)

    n, err := port.Write(b)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("port.Write: %v", err)
        }

    log.Println("Written bytes: ", n)

    //Sleep(1)

    res := make([]byte, 64)
        n, err = port.Read(res)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            log.Printf("port.Read: %v", err)
        }

    log.Println("READ bytes: ", n)


    printBuf(res)


    }

/*
I expect (for example):
---------
ATZ
OK
AT+CSQ
+CSQ 22.4
*/
```

Comment: You could try my [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program, it was written specifically for use cases like this, e.g. `echo AT+CSQ | atinout - /dev/ttyX -`.

Answer (score 1):

Most serial devices need a termination character to react to the commands they receive.

If you add it, your code should work:

```
var s string  = `AT+CSQ\r`
```

I don't see any other differences from your code and sending a command using a serial terminal. The same should apply when you echo the command directly onto the port file descriptor.

Comment: Answer appeared. but some "trash" like
f9 5 ef 21 7e ff 3 c0
d a 45 52 52 4f 52 d a
f9 5 ef 0 2 7e ff 3
(Command is `ATZ\r`)

Comment: It should be an NMEA string or GPS coordinates of some sort, right? Maybe you have to encode to ASCII?

Comment: this "trash" is what your `printBuf` was explicitly coded to produce, so I don't quite understand your confusion.

Comment: Hope [this](https://play.golang.org/p/DUPUv_dVOU9) will get you up to speed with this data.

Comment: I've tested your code with my GPS emulator and it works fine. If you want to print the answer you have to convert it to a string: `log.Println(string(res))`. If you still don't see the text then you likely have the wrong settings on your port (baud rate maybe?)

Comment: Now my code works fine, after some filters of excess  data.
But is there a way to query device with no blocking? When I query device, it cannot go to internet (((

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Golang seems to be quite SO dependent but on my machine (Linux) with a USB port your code does a non-blocking reading... Maybe you can try [a different library](https://github.com/tarm/serial) or write a Python script with pyserial, which is quite reliable.